# Send emails from shell script without local mailserver

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp, shell

How can I send email from a shellscript (usually cronjob) without running a mailserver on the same host. Using a smtp server. Running Ubuntu.

I looked a t various tutorials, but couldnt find a suitable approach (simple and secure).

Thanks

Sven

Answer (score 2):

You could install postfix or something else in relay-only mode and then use either mail(x) or mutt to send mail. Both can send mail from the command line.

A good option on Ubuntu might be nullmailer as MTA, as it is designed for relay-only operation.

Comment: ssmtp is another option that, as far as I can tell, does pretty much the same thing as nullmailer. I'd recommend something in that vein.

Answer (score 2):

If it's ubuntu then you have python and can use it's smtplib module (means no MTA on same host). There is a little sample posted below to get you started (you might want to put the username/pass/config in an ini file, do some error checking and such, but the ''starttls'' line encrypts the rest of the smtp session if the server supports it.). That gives you simple and secure.   It's possible to add attachments and so on with a little extra work.

You would call it like: mailsender.py "This is my message".

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
import sys

message = sys.argv[1]

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login('fromuser@gmail.com', 'password')
server.sendmail('fromuser@gmail.com', 'touser@somewhere.com', message)
server.rset()
server.quit()
```

You can call ''mailsender.py'' from your cron job or shellscripts.

Comment: I go for the groovy version (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990454/using-javamail-to-connect-to-gmail-smtp-server-ignores-specified-port-and-tries-t)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, having a Docker environment and a full featured MTA already in a container, so all typical ports already in use and thus can not run MTA as usual on Docker host where I want to send mails everytime a backup is completed.

Thanks to @davey I could extend his python script to send valid mails:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# script to send mail via smarthost
# (do NOT name this script "smtplib.py")

# edit settings
debuglevel   = 0
server_host  = 'localhost'
server_port  = 587
server_user  = 'me@myhost.com'
server_pass  = 'MyVerySecretP455W0RD'
address_from = 'me@myhost.com'
address_to   = 'myothermailbox@otherhost.com'
mail_subject = 'backup completed'

# load requirements
import datetime
import smtplib
import sys
# check if message was given, else show usage
try:
    sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print 'No message given! Usage: ' + sys.argv[0] + ' "my test message"'
    quit(1)
else:
    msg_content = sys.argv[1]
# format mailheader
msg_content = sys.argv[1]
msg_from = "From: " + address_from + "\r\n"
msg_to = "To: " + address_to + "\r\n"
msg_subject = "Subject: " + mail_subject + "\r\n"
msg_timestamp = '{:%a, %d %b %Y %H %M:%S %z}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
msg_date = "Date: " + msg_timestamp + "\r\n"
msg = msg_from + msg_to + msg_subject + msg_date + "\r\n" + msg_content
# connect to smarthost, login, send mail and disconnect
server = smtplib.SMTP(server_host, server_port)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
#server.ehlo()
server.login(server_user, server_pass)
server.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)
server.sendmail(address_from, address_to, msg)
server.rset()
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an email service that provides a REST api. I use [mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/pricing/). They offer a totally free (no CC required) account too. Just register with them and send post message using curl.